# How to store in Pentaho User Console Analysis Month number value instead Month name value

Tags: filter, pentaho, mondrian

Is possible somehow store **column number** instead **column name** in filter of saved analysis? My version of Pentaho User Console is 5.3. This is my **level** element in mondrian for month:

Stored values in database:

Values in **month_name** are: [Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr,...]
Values in **month_number** are: [1,2,3,..]

```
<Level name="month" visible="true" column="month_number" ordinalColumn="month_number" nameColumn="month_name" type="String" uniqueMembers="false" levelType="TimeMonths" hideMemberIf="Never" caption="%{polymis.dimension.timedimension.hierarchy.level.month.caption}">
        <Annotations>
          <Annotation name="AnalyzerDateFormat">
            <![CDATA[[yyyy].['Q'q].[MMM]]]>
          </Annotation>
        </Annotations>
      </Level>
```

Above you can see that i use **column="month_number"** so i thought that the value that will be stored in analysis file below like filtered value, but instead there is the value from **"month_name"**, for me this is invalid because i use localized values of months, so when i turned my language into another one this will not work for me in Pentaho user console.
The stored value should be rather

```
<filters>
        <filter formula="[timedimension].[month_name]" viewFilterEnum="MULTIPLE">
            <predicates>
                <predicate ordinal="1" operatorEnum="EQUAL">
                    <member formula="[timedimension].[2010].[Q1].[Mar]" caption="Mar" pos="0"/>
                </predicate>
            </predicates>
        </filter>
    </filters>
```

The result should be like below or something like that

```
<member formula="[timedimension].[2010].[Q1].[3]" caption="Mar"
     pos="0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an attribute

```
nameColumn="month_name"
```

You should be using `month_number` for the name attribute. As it's the same as the `column` attribute, you can simply delete it.

The `AnalyzerDateFormat` annotation also needs changing, from `[yyyy].['Q'q].[MMM]` to `[yyyy].['Q'q].[M]`.

Comment: When i do this in Pentaho User Console in your example the months will be displayed like **number**, i need to have **displayed names of months** in Pentaho User Console. When i select the filter [Mar] in Pentaho User Console for March and i will save the analysis it will be saved with value name of month [Mar], but i need to save **number** of month in analysis file, because i cannot use this with different localization where the value for March is [Mär] from German in my database

Comment: which analysis plugin are you using?